# Why do these expressions not work with this code?

Tags: c, linux

This is purely theory based, but I have this code:

```
int i = 3, k[] = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12}, *x = &i, *y = k;
double d = 1.5;
struct point_tag {
 int x, y;
 char *name;
} pt[] = {{200, 40, "begin"}, {300, 100, "end"}}, *pp = pt;
```

and these two expressions:

`pt[i--].y+50`   which causes undefined behavior at run time

`*(*pp.name+2)`    which does not compile

I would just like to know why the top one can not run and why the bottom one does not compile, even though `*((*pp).name+2)` does.

Comment: Read about operator precedence (`.` against `*`).

Comment: "which causes undefined behavior at run time" How do you know that it causes undefined behaviour if you don't know why?

Comment: Basically: don't write strange and needlessly complicated code and you won't get strange bugs. There is no reason why you should be doing `i--` at the point where you access the array, instead just use a for loop. There is no reason why you should do pointer de-referencing and arithmetic, just use the readable and bug free `[]` operator instead.

Comment: Please show a [mcve] next time, it will be much easier for everyone.

Answer (score 3):

> `pt[i--].y+50` which causes undefined behavior at run time

The array `pt` has the size of 2, because you added two initializer items. This results in valid index values as 0 and 1. `i` has an initial value of 3. You just access the array out of bounds.

> `*(*pp.name+2)` which does not compile

The operator preceedence favors `.` before `*`.

Answer (score 0):

You declared the array `pt` as having 2 elements. The variable `i` is initialized by the value `3`

```
int i = 3,...;
```

So this expression with the subscript operator

```
pt[i--].y+50
```

accesses memory beyond the array because the valid range of indices for the array is `[0, 2)`.

As for this expression

```
*(*pp.name+2)
```

then it is the same as the expression

```
*(*( pp.name ) + 2 )
```

As the variable `pp` is a pointer you may not apply the dot operator.

You need to write at least

```
*( ( *pp ).name+2)
```

Answer (score 0):

> `pt[i--].y+50` which causes undefined behavior at run time

`i` is stored the value `3` and you have only a two slots array.  As you have not specified a length in the brackets in de definition of the array, so the initializer indicates the size of the array, and the initializer has only two cells.  You can only access indices `0` and `1`, the rest is undefined behaviour. (`3` is two slots far out of the array).

> `*(*pp.name+2)` which does not compile

This is normal. field selection have higher preference than pointer dereference, so it is interpreted as `*((*(pp.name))+2)`, in which `pp.name` is invalid, as `pp` is a pointer, not a `struct`.  By the way, `(*pp)` is a `struct`, so `(*pp).name` will compile fine.

> I would just like to know why the top one can not run and why the bottom one does not compile, even though `*((*pp).name+2)` does.

this would compile because `*pp` is a `struct`, so the field accessor works `(*pp).name` is a pointer to `char`, so `(*pp).name + 2` (and the equivalent `pp->name + 2`) is **also a pointer** (a pointer pointing **to the third character of `pp->name`,** and `*((*pp).name + 2)` is the character pointed to (in the third position of the field name)

Finally, I'd recommend you that, if you want to end understanding the pointers and don't end hating them, you start with simpler expressions, use the `->` and `[]` operators (that are there to simplify pointer expressions, that look very unnatural due to operator precedence) and complicate things as long as you first understand the basic.